# New App provisioning in iPhone SDK 4 Beta

Tags: iphone, enterprise, provisioning, ios4

The enterprise distribution in iPhone 4 beta is supposed to be easier. Companies can host their own servers with the apps instead of distributing through iTunes.

I am looking for technical information on how to do this. Can someone refer to the documentation/online details regarding this?

Thank much.

Comment: Note that sdk 4.0 is under NDA so you should not discuss it on public forums.

Comment: You should take your question to http://devforums.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

There currently arent any details on Wireless Application Distribution available. And as Vlad said, it's confidential information anyway.

Searching the Apple Dev Forums, it seems you're not the only one wanting this information :)

Answer (score 0):

By 'host on your own server' they just mean host your apps as a file share.  It's the same as the regular dev way of doing things except you have a company provisioning profile that doesn't expire.  The process isn't any easier or harder than doing it as a dev.